# iptables allow traffic through wireguard gateway

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, linux-networking, wireguard

I have a server A running as gateway for some intranet connected on `eth0`. A is connected to multiple "relay nodes" like B, C, D... via WireGuard.

Assume here's the IP setup:

| Host | Address |
| --- | --- |
| A | 10.0.0.1/24 |
| B | 10.0.0.2/24 |
| C | 10.0.0.3/24 |

A routes *some* traffic through WG. Here's a part of A's routing table:

```
...
172.16.0.0/16 via 10.0.0.2 dev wg0
172.17.0.0/16 via 10.0.0.3 dev wg0
...
```

I would like to allow all traffic routed *through* B (`10.0.0.2`), while blocking traffic routed *through* C. With pseudo-code, this is what I'm thinking:

```
-A FORWARD -o wg0 --via 10.0.0.2 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o wg0 --via 10.0.0.3 -j DROP
#                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

There are a lot of items in the routing table that I don't want to repeat in iptables rules. Another problem is there's no MAC (or L2 in general) inside WG.

Is there any way to make this work?